# How to use more than one button in one field in Kendo Treelist?

Tags: kendo-ui, treelist

I want to use 2 or more buttons in one field like Kendo Grid by using custom command in TreeList  but I could not do that. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add an array of buttons to the column command property:

```
$("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    {
        command: [
            {
                name: "Cust1",
                text: "Custom1",
                click: function(e) {
                    alert("Custom1");
                }
            },
            {
                name: "Cust2",
                text: "Custom2",
                click: function(e) {
                    alert("Custom2");
                }
            },           
        ]
    }
  ],
  editable: true,
  dataSource: dataSource
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EHEVeh)**

Comment: thank you @ezanker, but can I ask you show me how to do that with Kendo HtmlHelper please?